# Group by partial string

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is my table:

```
----------+-----------+--------------
45678-sm-w|   18      | Mens clothing
----------+-----------+--------------
45678-sm-b|   5       | Mens clothing
----------+-----------+--------------
2189-L-Wh |   4       | Juniors Clothing
----------+-----------+--------------
2189-L-Bl |   3       | Juniors Clothing
----------+---------- +--------------
```

This is what the desired outcome is:

```
----------+-----------+--------------
45678     |   23      | Mens clothing
----------+-----------+--------------
2189      |   7       | Juniors Clothing
----------+-----------+--------------
```

Comment: Can you group by the third column instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you alter the table? It would make the most sense to alter the table by splitting `col1` into three columns (e.g. `id`, `size`, and `color`), so that you can just group by the new `id` column:

```
-----+----+----+-----------+--------------
45678| sm | w  |   18      | Mens clothing
-----+----+----+-----------+--------------
45678| sm | b  |   5       | Mens clothing
-----+----+----+-----------+--------------
2189 |  L | Wh |   4       | Juniors Clothing
-----+----+----+-----------+--------------
2189 |  L | Bl |   3       | Juniors Clothing
-----+----+----+---------- +--------------
```

You can accomplish this by using `ALTER TABLE` to add the three columns you need and change the primary key, using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `UPDATE` to extract and store the split values, and another `ALTER TABLE` to cleanup. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t
DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE T
ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ADD size VARCHAR(255),
ADD color VARCHAR(255),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1);

UPDATE TABLE t
SET id = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER),
SET size = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 2),
SET color = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 3);

ALTER TABLE t
DROP COLUMN col1;
```

---

If you can't alter the table, you can extract the id number you need using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1), col2, col3 FROM table;
```

gives:

```
-----+-----------+--------------
45678|   18      | Mens clothing
-----+-----------+--------------
45678|   5       | Mens clothing
-----+-----------+--------------
2189 |   4       | Juniors Clothing
-----+-----------+--------------
2189 |   3       | Juniors Clothing
-----+---------- +--------------
```

For the final query, I would use one `SELECT` to extract the id you need, and an outer `SELECT` for the grouping:

```
SELECT id, SUM(col2) AS total, col3
FROM 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1) AS id, col2, col3
    FROM table) AS t
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are selecting the data, then you can use something like this:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1) col1, 
  sum(col2) Total, 
  col3
from table1
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(col3, ' ', 1)
order by col1 desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86d78/5)

Comment: I might be able to use this and turn it into a view for later reference

Answer (score 0):

CAST the first column to a number, add an index to the newly created column and run a group by sum on that column.

```
update table set `left`=CAST(col1 AS SIGNED );

select `left`,sum(*),`col3` from table;
```

Comment: I agree that Tyler should alter the table, but not this way. If you are going to change the table, do it correctly and completely: split col1 into three columns: `id`, `size`, and `color`. Then you just group by `id`.

Comment: How would I split it into the three columns?